# SharePoint 2010 401 error

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

We have a SharePoint 2010 server on a domain machine. Now we try to login to that server with domain users using web service calls , However we are getting 401 error while logging in  .We have checked that the windows authentication for the particular web application (IIS site ) is disabled , so we enabled it .. Are there any other reasons for which login fails ?

Answer (score 0):

Can the Domain User actually login to sharepoint, eg do they have access to Root site on the site collection?